# Cancel Edit in Modal - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a noobie ReactJS developer learning the basics.

This is simple, I am missing a very basic functionality of react.

I created a basic sample app. 
It has a transaction table. 'Double click' on each row opens the edit modal. I am  looking for a way to add `cancel` button to modal to cancel the performed edits and revert the `state` to the original.

I have bound each field in the modal to edit like this

```
      <input
             type="text"
             className="form-control"                        
             value={props.transData.date}
             onChange={(event) => props.changeDate(event, props.transData.id)} />
```

I have defined the event handler like this

```
 changeDateHandler = (event, rowId) => {
        let newTransactions = Array.from(this.state.transactions) ;
        newTransactions.find(trans => trans.id === rowId).date = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            transactions: newTransactions
        });
    }
```

The state looks like this: (Hard Coded. I have not connected to server)

```
state = {
        selectedTrans: null,
        transEditing: false,
        transactions: [
            { id: 1, date: '01/12/1990', payee: 'Reliance', amount: 900 },
            { id: 2, date: '01/12/1990', payee: 'Reliance', amount: 900 },
            { id: 3, date: '01/12/1990', payee: 'Reliance', amount: 900 }
        ]
    }
```

I have tried to revert the state in the componentDidUpdate LifeCyle like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        this.prevTransaction = {...prevState.selectedTrans};
        console.log(prevState.selectedTrans);
    }
```

I was planning to revert the state using the `prevState`.
But the `prevState` is not showing the previous value. It always show the present edited value.

Where am I going wrong? Is there any other way to implement the Cancel functionality of the modal?

Comment: Don't try to "revert" changes. Just make another state for new/edited transactions and when "OK" button is clicked, set that value as a `transactions` state. If "Cancel" button is clicked, clear the editing state and that's it. No need to change `transactions` state. Do you get it?

Comment: @bravemaster  ok Let me try that way.  But why am I not getting the prevState in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: If you're new to react and this is just a sample project, don't get into `componentDidMount`. Instead start with React hooks. They're easier to understand and simpler to develop. It's hard to tell why you code does not work given this amount of code by the way. Anyway, `componentDidMount` is not meant to be used like your way.